# Restricting variable use to one file

Tags: php, model-view-controller, variables, view

Bit of a weird question but bear with me. I'm writing a small MVC framework mostly for learning purposes. When I load views, I just include the view file and then use `extract($data);` so I can use variables in my view. This is that it looks like in my controller:

```
// Assign view variables and load the views
$data = array('title' => 'testing the framework',
              'users' => $this->models['Users']->getAllUsers());
$this->loadViews(array('header', 'home', 'footer'), $data);
```

It works perfectly, but it just occured to me that if I have any variables elsewhere in my project that are called `$title` or `$users`, they will conflict to what I'm `extract()`'ing. THis hasn't become a problem yet but I have a feeling I need to deal with it now before it does.

The only solution I've found is using a prefix for the variables being `extract()`ed. SO I can use them in my template like `<?php echo $tpl_whatever; ?>` instead of `<?php echo $whatever; ?>`

Can anyone offer some advice? Maybe a way I can limit the variables scope?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you even aware that [template](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html) and view are different things? Views in MVC design pattern contain all of the UI/presentation logic. They create generate response that might or might not be generated by combining multiple templates. Also, while on the subject, model is a layer. Not a class. Nor an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will no conflict with other controller because the $data variables that you are extracting are private. Also if your variable has duplicate inside your controllers function, the last declaration will be the one to be used.

Answer (score 3):

Only variables in your method can have conflict [See Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) but if such happens you can resolved conflict in [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) easy with extra flags such as `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL`.

You can also look at `EXTR_PREFIX_SAME` , `EXTR_SKIP` or `EXTR_OVERWRITE` to resolve possible collusion during extraction

Your Variables

```
$name = "Baba";
$array = array("title" => "Restricting variable use to one file",
               "name"  => "James Dawson");
```

Example `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL`

```
extract($array,EXTR_PREFIX_ALL,"new");
var_dump($new_title,$new_name,$name);
           ^------------------------------ it now has prifix
```

Output

```
string 'Restricting variable use to one file' (length=36)
string 'James Dawson' (length=12)
string 'Baba' (length=4)
```

Example `EXTR_PREFIX_SAME`

```
extract($array, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "prifix");
var_dump($name,$title,$prifix_name);
                           ^------------------ Only Conflict has prifix
```

Output

```
string 'Baba' (length=4)
string 'Restricting variable use to one file' (length=36)
string 'James Dawson' (length=12)
```